# Extracting parts of file names with a given suffix in C++

Tags: c++

I know this is relatively trivial but I'm new to C++ and am getting lost between all the library functions.

In the directory of the program I'm running I have some files with a name of the form SUFFIX_ordinal.xml. (F.E.: SUFFIX_34.xml, SUFFIX_75.xml..)

I need to iterate through all the files in the directory, find these files and extract their ordinals. (F.E.: 34, 75).

Can you help? I don't even know where to start. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to iterate files in the directory? Numerals are fixed size 00,01,35,99 or variable size 1,2,42,24024? Suffixes are fixed to three characters?

Answer (score 1):

Typically [`boost.filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm) to iterate through the file names.

Though many people wouldn't approve, extracting the ordinals may be easiest with `sscanf`, something like: `sscanf(filename, "SUFFIX_%d.xml", &ordinal);`

If you prefer to avoid `sscanf` (hard to blame you), it's still fairly easy with something like a `stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream buffer(filename);

buffer.ignore(100, '_');
buffer >> ordinal;
```